# 'Responsive' and 'fixed on top' table header: from jQuery to AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, responsive-design

I am working on a table and I want to achieve that it's header stays `fixed at TOP`. I have tried doing an implementation in `jQuery` and it seems to be working but... I have the following problems:

1. If am not writing css the table header `<td>` elements shrinks to
   it's element width
2. I have to write a lot of `media-queries` to satiate different devices (I am tired)
3. It's not responsive.

> Here is a **plunkr** of what I have already achieved in **jQuery**:
>   http://plnkr.co/edit/JLkIsHNsIoLkZk5LanrK?p=info

```
$(function() {
  var table = $('table'),
      thead = table.find('thead'),
      fixed_thead,
      the_window = $(window);

  thead.find('td').each(function() {
    var el = $(this);
    el.css('width', el.Width());
  });

  fixed_thead = thead.clone().hide();
  thead.after(fixed_thead);

  fixed_thead.css({
    'position': 'fixed',
    'top': 0,
    'width': thead.width()
  });

  the_window.scroll(function() {
    if (the_window.scrollTop() > table.offset().top) {
      fixed_thead.show();
    } else {
      fixed_thead.hide();
    }

  });
});
```

I now want to achieve this same behaviour when we have 10 columns and a large data set to populate the table *but* using **AngularJS**.

Comment: [look here](http://jsfiddle.net/f2XYF/16/) Just looked for this also

Comment: @Dvir, thanks for the sample,but am not looking for an inside scroll,in the table itself,

Comment: I guess you want your **jQuery** code in **AngularJS**, don't you?

Comment: @charliebrownie ,i want the piece in angular,am not sure if all the code from jquery will be in angular supported jquery classes,but yes i want it in AngularJS and desperately need it to be responsive.. Thanks